# Magento2 - How to clear data from jQuery modal popup after closing modal?

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery, modal-popup

Here am using jQuery popup in my `.phtml` file on the first run it sending data properly, on send time it fetching old data as-swell as new data. So how to prevent this condition.
Code:

```
    <div class="popUpDiv" id="popup-modal">
                      <select id="reason_id" name="field1">
                        <option value="R000001">Order Created by Mistake</option>
                        <option value="R000002">Items would not arrive on time</option>
                        <option value="R000003">Shipping cost is too high</option>
                        <option value="R000004">Item price is too high</option>
                        <option value="R000005">Need to change order details or payment method</option>
                        <option value="R000006">Others</option>
                      </select>
                        <textarea class="reason_msg" name ="field2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>
                      <div class="submit_btn_div">
                        <button  name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
<?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>

    <button class="cancel_order gray-btn" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Cancel') ?></a></button>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is my jQuery for modal popup:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($){
        // $(".popUpDiv").hide();
      $('.reason_msg').hide();
      $(".cancel_order").click(function(){
        console.log("here 1");
         var reason_msg = '';
          var order_id = $(this).val();
           console.log(order_id);

            // $(".popUpDiv").show();
             $("#reason_id").change(function(){
                if($('#reason_id').val() == 'R000006'){
                    $('.reason_msg').show();
                 }else{
                    $('.reason_msg').hide();
                 }
              });

             $("#submit").click(function(){
                console.log("here");
$("#popup-modal").modal('closeModal');
                    $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
                    $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');

             });
      });
});
```

---

```
require(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
],
function($,modal
) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
          $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
         //For reset textarea
    $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');
        });
    });

$('#popup-modal').on('modalclosed', function() {
           //For reset Select field
    $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
         //For reset textarea
    $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');

});

      $(".cancel_order").click(function(){
         $("#popup-modal").modal('openModal');
      });
        var options = {
        type: 'popup',
        responsive: true,
        innerScroll: true,
        cache: false,
        title: 'Select a Reason to Cancel',
        modalClass: 'custom-modal',
        buttons: [{
            text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
            class: 'module_pop',
            click: function () {
                    $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
                             //For reset textarea
                    $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');
                this.closeModal();

            }
        }]

    };
    var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
    return false;
  }
);
```

Where am I doing wrong? can I get help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using form tag in your modal popup then you can simply reset that form when modal popup close or set all field value with blank.

```
------
click: function () 
{
    $('#form_id').trigger("reset");
              //OR
    $("input[name='field1']").val('');
    $("input[name='field2']").val('');
    $("input[name='field3']").val('');
         //For reset Select field
    $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
         //For reset textarea
    $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');

    this.closeModal();
}
```

> OR

```
$('#popup-modal').on('modalclosed', function() {
    $('#form_id').trigger("reset");
               //OR
    $("input[name='field1']").val('');
    $("input[name='field2']").val('');
    $("input[name='field3']").val('');
         //For reset Select field
    $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
         //For reset textarea
    $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');
 });
```

You can try below code:

```
<div class="popUpDiv" id="popup-modal">
    <form name="customform" id="customform" method="POST" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>" >
        <select id="reason_id" name="field1">
            <option value="R000001">Order Created by Mistake</option>
            <option value="R000002">Items would not arrive on time</option>
            <option value="R000003">Shipping cost is too high</option>
            <option value="R000004">Item price is too high</option>
            <option value="R000005">Need to change order details or payment method</option>
            <option value="R000006">Others</option>
        </select>
        <textarea class="reason_msg" name ="field2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>
        <div class="submit_btn_div">
            <button name="submit" id="data_submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
    $,
    modal
    ) {
        var options = {
        type: 'popup',
        responsive: true,
        innerScroll: true,
        buttons:false
        };
        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
        $("#button").on("click", function(){
                $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    require(['jquery','mage/validation'],function($){
        $("#data_submit").on("click",function(event){
            var customform =$('#popup-modal form[id=customform]');
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            if(customform.validation() && !customform.validation('isValid')) {
                return false;
            }
            var url = "<?php echo $block->getUrl('custom/index/send') ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: customform.serialize(),
                showLoader: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    $('#popup-modal').on('modalclosed', function() {
                        $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
                        $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $("#btn-cancel").on("click",function(){
            $("#popup-modal").modal("closeModal");
        });
        $('#popup-modal').on('modalclosed', function() {
            //For reset Select field
            $('#reason_id').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            //For reset textarea
            $("textarea[name='field2']").val('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: thank you for replaying, I Used both methods but there is no change.
my input fields are:
 `<select id="reason_id" name="field1">
    <option value="R000001">option1</option>
    <option value="R000002">option1</option>
</select>
<textarea class="reason_msg" name ="field2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>`

Comment: Hello @PraveenNegimani, you are used select & textarea fields, it's not consider as an input field, please check my updated answer.

Comment: I changed as your answer but its still showing no changes

Comment: Can you please update or add your whole code?

Comment: Did you cleaned / flush cache after updated changes in PHTML file?

Comment: yes I flushed cache, I updated my Code Please check.
am getting error:
`modal.js:445 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104920/discussion-between-praveen-negimani-and-rohit).